# Unable to bind my List to datagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

I was working on a project in which I was binding my custom list to a datagrid. I thought I might have some issues in my current application, so I decided to make a new sample application in 4.0 but same issue.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form` 
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void populate()
        {
            List<BillInfoCustom> oSalesList = new List<BillInfoCustom>();

            BillInfoCustom oSalesType = new BillInfoCustom() { BillId = 1, BillDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), CashPayment = 10, CreditCardPaymet = 20, CustomerName = "asda", TotalPrice = 20.0 };

            BillInfoCustom oSalesType2 = new BillInfoCustom() { BillId = 1, BillDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), CashPayment = 10, CreditCardPaymet = 20, CustomerName = "asda", TotalPrice = 20.0 };

            BillInfoCustom oSalesType3 = new BillInfoCustom() { BillId = 1, BillDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), CashPayment = 10, CreditCardPaymet = 20, CustomerName = "asda", TotalPrice = 20.0 };

            oSalesList.Add(oSalesType);
            oSalesList.Add(oSalesType2);
            oSalesList.Add(oSalesType3);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = oSalesList;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            populate();
        }
    }

    public class BillInfoCustom
    {
        public int BillId;
        public double TotalPrice;
        public double CashPayment;
        public double CreditCardPaymet;
        public string CustomerName;
        public string BillDate;
    }
}
```

And here is the output after I press button:

[image: output]

Comment: it wasnt, had tried this too. and my case is diffrent than your mentioned question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data binding works on properties, not fields. You add `{ get; set; }` to each member. Try changing to:

```
public class BillInfoCustom
{
    public int BillId { get; set; }

    public double TotalPrice{ get; set; }

    public double CashPayment { get; set; }

    public double CreditCardPaymet { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public string BillDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: does the trick. so as your first Answere on SO